# componentWillUnmount() method not working after deleting DOM element

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand how `camponentWillUnmount()` method really works in React, and to do so, I have created a little example which is not working as expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PageDescription from '../PageDescription/PageDescription';

class LifeCycle extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            deleteInfo: false,
        }

        this.deleteDescription = this.deleteDescription.bind(this);
    }


    deleteDescription() {
        this.setState({
            deleteInfo: true,
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('inside componentWillUnmount method');
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container col-6">
                <h1>Page Title</h1>
                <hr />
                <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
                {!this.state.deleteInfo && <PageDescription />}
                <hr />
                {!this.state.deleteInfo && <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.deleteDescription()}>Delete paragraph</button>}
            </div>
        );
    }¿
}

export default LifeCycle;
```

After the first render, if I click on `Delete paragraph` button, PageDescription component is deleted from the DOM, but the method `componentWillUnmount()` method is never called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `componentWillUnmount` method will be called by the React lifecycle when the component will be unmounted, in your example, this method will be called when the component `<LifeCylce />` will be unmounted, not the `PageDescription` component

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d5pwbrev/)

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood.

Comment: Just added an example for you

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillUnmount` is the last `function` to be called immediately before the `component` is removed from the `DOM`. It is generally used to perform clean-up for any `DOM-elements` or timers created in `componentWillMount`.
For more info you can refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are completing misunderstood the `compononentwillunmount` lifecycle.
The `compononentwillunmount` cycle is the code related to `<LifeCycle />` not `<PageDescription />`. So in your question, the cycle will not trigger as it is a part of `lifeCycle` component not the other component that is being destroyed. On solution can be to call `compononentwillunmount` in `PageDescription` component.